# Create XML File IN SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a store procedure that is supposed to generate an XML file based on data available in a table. If there are data in all the fields, it work fine. However, if there are no date in one or more of the fields, it does not create the xml. It return null instead. I started debugging it and noticed that @part1 has the correct value, part2 has the correct value, and part3 has the correct value. Once I concatenate them, I noticed part1 is now null. What am I missing here?

```
select @part1 = '<Students>';

            @part2 ='<NumberOFCourse>'+isnull(convert(varchar,(select NumberOFCourse from Courses)), 0)+'</NumberOFCourse>' ;
                select @part3 = '<NumberOFSemesterCredit>'+isnull(convert(varchar,(select NumberOFSemesterCredit from Courses)), 0)'</NumberOFSemesterCredit>' +
                '</Students>';
                select @part1 += @part2 + @part3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted the code you are actually using because there are several typos in there and when those are fixed it does not show the behavior that you describe so I can't tell you why your code does not work for you.

Instead of using string concatenation to build the XML you could use [PATH Mode with FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) something like this.

```sql
select C.NumberOFCourse,
       C.NumberOFSemesterCredit
from Courses as C
for xml path('Students')
```